# Customizing PropertyGrid Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to customize a property wherein if I click the elipses button [...] a new dialog form will be displayed. Unfortunately, the form won't show. Can you please check the below code and advise where did I go wrong?

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
using System;

namespace Test01
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form form = new Form();

            propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new MyType();

        }
    }

    class MyType
    {
        private string bar;

        [Editor(typeof(FooEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
        public string Bar
        {
            get { return bar; }
            set { bar = value; }
        }
    }

    [Editor(typeof(FooEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    class Foo
    {
        private string bar;
        public string Bar
        {
            get { return bar; }
            set { bar = value; }
        }
    }
    class FooEditor : UITypeEditor
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }
        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            IWindowsFormsEditorService svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;
            Foo foo = value as Foo;
            if (svc != null && foo != null)
            {
                using (FooForm form = new FooForm())
                {
                    form.Value = foo.Bar;
                    if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        foo.Bar = form.Value; // update object
                    }
                }
            }
            return value; // can also replace the wrapper object here
        }
    }
    class FooForm : Form
    {
        private TextBox textbox;
        private Button okButton;
        public FooForm() 
        {
            textbox = new TextBox();
            Controls.Add(textbox);
            okButton = new Button();
            okButton.Text = "OK";
            okButton.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            okButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            Controls.Add(okButton);
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return textbox.Text; }
            set { textbox.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your editor works with the `Foo` type (if `value` isn't `Foo` then it won't show the dialog) but you create an instance of `MyType`, it contains one property `Bar` of type `string` then it can't be edited by your `FooEditor`.

To try how your code works you should change the property `Bar` from `string` to `Foo`:

```
class MyType
{
    private Foo bar = new Foo();

    [Editor(typeof(FooEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public Foo Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { bar = value; }
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLES**
Let's see two examples. In the first one you edit the property where the `Attribute` has been applied (then your editor changes the value of the property itself):

This is the class you'll edit in the `PropertyGrid`, I removed the `Foo` class because useless for this example:

```
class MyType
{
    private string bar;

    [Editor(typeof(MyStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public string Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { bar = value; }
    }
}
```

This is the editor that will edit your `Bar` property. Actually it works with any property of type `string`:

```
class MyStringEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        var svc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        string text = value as string;
        if (svc != null && text != null)
        {
            using (FooForm form = new FooForm())
            {
                form.Value = text;
                if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    return form.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Now another example, the editor doesn't change the property value itself but the value of a property of that property (editor is applied to property `MyType.Bar` (of type `Foo`) but it changes the value of the property `Value` of `Foo`.

Let's introduce again a complex type for your `Bar` property:

```
class Foo
{
    private string _value;
    private object _tag; // Unused in this example

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public object Tag
    {
        get { return _tag; }
        set { _value = _tag; }
    }
}
```

Change the `MyType` class to publish one property of the complex type we wrote, note that the `EditorAttribute` now uses a new editor specific for the `Foo` type:

```
class MyType
{
    private Foo bar = new Foo();

    [Editor(typeof(FooEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public Foo Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { bar = value; }
    }
}
```

Finally we write the editor for the `Foo` type. Please note that this editor will change only the value of the property `Foo.Value`, the other property exposed by `Foo` won't be touched:

```
class FooEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        var svc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        Foo foo = value as Foo;
        if (svc != null && foo != null)
        {
            using (FooForm form = new FooForm())
            {
                form.Value = foo.Value;
                if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // Updates the value of the property Value
                    // of the property we're editing. 
                    foo.Value = form.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        // In this case we simply return the original property
        // value, the property itself hasn't been changed because
        // we updated the value of an inner property
        return value;
    }
}
```

Last notes: in the `if` block of `svc.ShowDialog()` we have the update value from the `Form`, the property `Bar` (where the editor is applied) won't be changed but we'll update the `Value` property of the `Foo` instance it contains. Roughly equivalent to write something like this:

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
myType.Bar.Value = form.Value;
```

If we just return a new value for the property (like in the previous example) the old value of `Tag` property will be lost, something like this:

```
MyType myType = new MyType();
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Value = form.Value;
myType.Bar = foo;
```

Can you see the difference? Anyway it's going to be too more a tutorial than an answer...

Please note that examples are untested, I just wrote them here, I just would like to expose the concept more than to provide a surely working example.

**REFERENCES**

Here you can find a short list of useful resources:

- A [comprehensive example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx) about how `UITypeEditor` works
- Main source for `PropertyDescriptor` documentation is always MSDN but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5988/Unleash-PropertyGrid-with-Dynamic-Properties-and-G) you can find a pretty short example.
- If you just need to localize property names you may take a look to [this entry here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193770/how-to-refresh-localized-attributes-in-propertygrid).